# SELECT MIN(column) LIMIT to the top 5 lowest values

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I need to get the top 5 MIN(column) entries from a table 'bids'.

table bids:

[image]

I tried using

> SELECT * FROM bids ORDER BY bid ASC LIMIT 5;

this is the result:

[image]

but the problem is that if 'bid' wont bring the top 10, it would just bring the lowest entries, it doesn't matter if they are repeated.

this is the result that im expecting:

[image]

Comment: lease read https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql and make a [mre]

Comment: Thankyou! i just updated!

Comment: You probably need to add a `group by` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MIN(col)` finds the smallest value

"TOP" in some other engines means "the first".

Do you want the rows with the smallest values?  Or the largest?

```
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY bid ASC LIMIT 10;  -- The smallest
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY bid DESC LIMIT 10;  -- The largest
```

Based on your edit, you want something more like

```
SELECT bid FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT bid FROM bids ) t
    ORDER BY bid ASC
    LIMIT 10
```

If you also need the other columns, it gets messy.  First, which value of the other column do you want?

```
SELECT bid, MAX(id)
    FROM bids
    GROUP BY bid
    ORDER BY bid
    LIMIT 10;

SELECT bid, COUNT(*)
    FROM bids
    GROUP BY bid
    ORDER BY bid
    LIMIT 10;
```

If neither of those is satisfactory, then you get into "groupwise-max" issues.  See the tag I added and see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

"GROUP BY" and "DISTINCT" do *similar* things.  I like to be careful which I use for which case.

Comment: What does the 't' stands for?
Also, is there a way to select all the content from bid (if theres any other column)?

Comment: @ChristopherMartinez - `t` is an "alias".  It is an arbitrary name for the subquery.  If you leave it off, you will get an error message that explains it slightly more.

Comment: @ChristopherMartinez - and I added to my Answer.